# How do I print a list in a triangular shape in python?

Tags: python

I have a code that generates a list of values to form a Romberg Triangle. The list is always a triangular length (3, 6, 10, 15). How do I print a list like this in triangular form?

What I currently have:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

Print statement that I want:

```
1 
2 5 
3 6 8
4 7 9 10
```

Comment: can you show us another example list and expected output?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
def getLength(n):
    i = 1
    s = 1
    while ( s < n ):
        i += 1
        s = s + i
    return i

def printTriangle(a):
    l = len(a)
    lt = getLength(l)
    for i in range(lt):
        d = lt - 2
        s = 0
        for j in range(i+1):
            print(a[i+j+s], end=' ')
            s += d
            d -= 1
        print('')

a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

printTriangle(a)
```

The `getLength` function just calculates the height of the triangle and the `printTriangle` function handles the actual printing logic.

Comment: Error occurs when you add just one extra list element.

Comment: @Hamidzreza Well yes, it is supposed that the elements will always be in the count 3, 6, 10, 15 as stated in the question.

Answer (score 1):

A different approach:

```
def print_tri(l):
    n_rows = 1
    n_elements = 1
    while n_elements < len(l):
        n_rows += 1
        n_elements += n_rows

    rows = [[] for _ in range(n_rows)]
    offset = 0
    while l:
        for d in range(offset, n_rows):
            rows[d].append(l.pop(0))
        offset += 1

    for row in rows:
        print(' '.join(map(str, row)))

print_tri([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10])
```

Answer (score 1):

One can go full-math, solving `length=(n*(n+1))/2` for `n` (number of rows and columns, it has one positive solution), and then use the sum of arithmetic progression for calculating indices for the columns (what the older variant below does using `sum`):

```
def tri(lst):
  rows=int(((1+8*len(lst))**0.5-1)/2)
  for row in range(0,rows):
    print([lst[int(row+(2*rows-column-1)*column/2)] for column in range(0,row+1)])
  print() # this is just for separating subsequent calls

tri([1])
tri([1,2,3])
tri([1,2,3,4,5,6])
tri([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])
tri([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15])
```

Output:

> ```
> [1]
>
> [1]
> [2, 3]
>
> [1]
> [2, 4]
> [3, 5, 6]
>
> [1]
> [2, 5]
> [3, 6, 8]
> [4, 7, 9, 10]
>
> [1]
> [2, 6]
> [3, 7, 10]
> [4, 8, 11, 13]
> [5, 9, 12, 14, 15]
> ```

---

An older variant collecting column-lengths first, and then indexing into the list directly:

```
a=list(range(1,11))
lena=len(a)

deltas=[]
total=0
i=0
while total<lena:
  deltas.append(i)
  i+=1
  total+=i
lend=len(deltas)

for row in range(lend):
  print([a[row+sum(deltas[lend-column:])] for column in range(0,row+1)])
```

Answer (score 1):

The following works fairly efficiently:

```
def print_triangle(x):
    it = iter(x)
    num = 0
    while True:
        val = next(it, None)
        if val:
            print(val, *(next(it) for _ in range(num)))
            num += 1
        else:
            break
```

```
>>> print_triangle([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10])
1
2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9 10
>>> print_triangle([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
1
2 3
4 5 6
```

Will fail if the input doesn't have the correct length:

```
>>> print_triangle([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
1
2 3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 7, in <genexpr>
StopIteration

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 7, in print_triangle
RuntimeError: generator raised StopIteration
```

Answer (score 1):

I have used a lot of mathematics! `n` is the side of triangle (I have used [delta equation](https://sciencing.com/delta-math-6678201.html) to calculate that). `l` is the list of numbers you can give to the function. I hope the rest would be understandable!! Feel free to ask questions in comment.

```
def print_triang(l):
    lg = len(l)
    number_of_rows = int(((1+8*lg)**.5 - 1) / 2)
    for row_index in range(number_of_rows):
        print(' '.join(
            str(l[x]) for x in [row_index + col_index*number_of_rows - int(col_index*(col_index+1)/2) for col_index in range(row_index+1)]
    ))
```

Comment: `number_of_rows = (-1+(1+8*lg)**0.5)/2` and can check that `number_of_rows == int(number_of_rows)` for valid list length

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `next` with `iter`:

```
def is_side(d, s):
  return not d if not s else is_side(d[s:], s-1)

def to_triangle(d):
   new_d, r = iter(d), [i for i in range(len(d)) if is_side(d, i)][0]
   s = [[next(new_d) for _ in range(i)] for i in reversed(range(1, r+1))]
   return '\n'.join(' '.join(str(b[x]) if (x:=len(b) - len(s[0])+i) >= 0 else ' ' for b in s) for i in range(len(s[0])))

d = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
print(to_triangle(d))
```

Output:

```
1      
2 5    
3 6 8  
4 7 9 10
```